# How to broadcast message to all registered users with sinch and parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform, sinch

I am trying to implement a shoutbox for Android app. I am following the tutorial below and works perfectly for me:
https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-messaging-tutorial-using-sinch-and-parse/

My problem is that right now, I get a list of all registered users on Parse and then send a message to each one of them using Sinch:

```
messageService.sendMessage(groupUserIdList, messageBody);
```

I may potentially have thousands of users so the groupUserIdList will be huge. This looks inefficient and I am looking for a better way to do this.

Does Sinch offer a broadcast, such that I can send messages to all registered users without creating the groupUserIdList everytime?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, that would be ineffective.
We are not really a mass communication platform like that. WE are more about user to user and small groups. So I would not use our messaging to send a IM to thousands of people.

Comment: Can we get all list of all current userID without using parse but only sinch?

Comment: Sorry no, we dont provide a userDatabase